# Animated Boolean Modifier is flickering

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I have some troubles with the Boolean Modifier.

[image: Boolean Modifier Error]]

That happens every few frames when I'm rotating or moving it.
I had noticed later after I had rendered an animation. This was very annoying.
Here is a simplified scene with the same problem:

[image: The same as in this picture]

How can I fix this this problem?

Comment: Check this in version 2.73a
I traced flickering errors to be introduced to version 2.74 and not fixed. It is same error in version 2.78a
https://youtu.be/lIv6qLm5WfU

Comment: This is an old question but perhaps this will help someone:
From my experience, this can happen if the two shapes: 

- Have overlapping edges... (I think that's your problem.) just offset them some.
- If the shapes are non manifold/ not completely enclosed... or normal not all facing the same way. recalculate normals.
- Complex shapes, multiple complete shapes in one object, overlapping shapes...

Also with 2.78 we have the b-mesh solver. Switching between the solvers sometimes solves the problem. But I'd avoid using booleans in animation where possible.